# How to properly use INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGERs to remove a node from a tree structure memorized on an SQL Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, triggers, tree

I have a Microsoft SQL Server that contains a database which has a table named `Tree` designed to store a tree, with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TREE 
(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
 parent INT REFERENCES Tree(id)
)
```

An example of the table once populated could be the following:

```
ID PARENT
 1 NULL
 2 NULL
 3 1
 4 1
 5 2
 6 2
 7 3
 8 3
 9 5
```

What I want to achieve is that upon deleting a node, all of his children also get deleted.

At first I thought this would have been an easy task, and that it could be solved by simply setting an `ON DELETE CASCADE` action on the foreign key constraint, but SQL Server does not permit this operation because it **doesn't allow** neither `ON DELETE` nor `ON UPDATE` to generate **cycles**. (it doesn't check if cycles are actually generated, so it denies every configuration that could possibly generate one, and this is one of those: weird choice to me considering that stored procedures allow 32 levels of recursion)

I tried using **recursive triggers** believing that the foreign key constraint would have been checked only after the recursive call was completed, in the following way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insteadOfDeleteTrigger on Tree INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE idsToBeRemoved TABLE (id INT);
 INSERT INTO idsToBeRemoved SELECT id FROM deleted;

 DELETE FROM Tree WHERE parent IN (SELECT id FROM idsToBeRemoved);
 DELETE FROM Tree WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM idsToBeRemoved);
END;
```

Even though this clearly is not the solution, as the last line makes an unwanted recursive call to the trigger resulting in an infinite recursion (which would get interrupted by the recursion level limit of 32 imposed by SQL Server), the fact that surprised me is that the execution never reaches that instruction, as upon deleting the first level of children, foreign key constraints are checked and found to be broken because of children of the next level, resulting in the impossibility of performing this task with triggers.

How would you perform this operation? Is there a way to not employ non-trigger stored procedures?

**EDIT:** As I finally figured out, INSTEAD OF DELETE triggers are not meant to be used for custom deletion of data from a table, they are instead meant to be used to prevent a deletion that will in fact never take place, but will change data on some other table that in turn will make the original data appear as deleted.

This is particularly useful when used in combination with views, that normally do not support DELETE operations. By defining an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger which deletes/updates data from the table on which the view is created, one may obtain a fully table-like view, resulting in another layer between the user and the data, that comes handy for many operations.

To solve my specific issue, instead, I had to make every deletion go trough a stored procedure that i designed to perform the full operation. Will post it here soon enough.

Comment: You don't need triggers to implement a recursive algorithm. You can do that yourself using procedure calls. There are other solutions as well to recursively delete.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this. id = 3 is a node that I want to delete together with two of its children

```
;with x as
(
    select  id, parent
    from    tree
    where   id = 3

    union all

    select  y.id, y.parent
    from    tree as y
        join x on x.id = y.parent
)
delete  t
from    tree as t
        join x on t.id = x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
CREATE TABLE TREE 
(
 id INT primary key,
 parent INT REFERENCES Tree(id)
)
go
insert into Tree (id,parent) values
(1,NULL ),
(2,NULL ),
(3,1    ),
(4,1    ),
(5,2    ),
(6,2    ),
(7,3    ),
(8,3    ),
(9,5    )
go
create trigger T_Tree_D on Tree
instead of delete
as
    ;With AllRows as (
        select id from deleted
        union all
        select t.id from Tree t inner join AllRows ar on t.parent = ar.id
    )
    delete from Tree where id in (select id from AllRows)
go
delete from Tree where id=3
go
select * from Tree
```

Result:

```
id          parent
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           NULL
4           1
5           2
6           2
9           5
```

You may have to adjust the [`MAXRECURSION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) option if you have particularly deep trees. But this is using the SQL Server feature most suitable for dealing with recursion - the [Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).